# Тире или запятая

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

> Хотите увидеть лучшие закаты, отправляйтесь в Доминикану.

Допустима ли здесь запятая вместо тире?

Answer (score 2):

```
   Допустима ли здесь запятая вместо тире?
```

Допустима где? В учебном материале, т.е. в дом. заданиях, - явная ошибка, ведь это бессоюзное сложное предложение с условными отношениями (если...- то...), должно быть тире, запятая предполагает равноправные действия, совершаемые одновременно или последовательно.

Если же это запись где-то в блоге, допустимо, но только это тоже ваше лицо, если хотите, чтобы люди считали Вас грамотным блогером, нужно соблюдать орфографическую и пунктуационную грамотность. По-моему, с тире фраза приобретает стройность и точность мысли.

*Хотите увидеть лучшие закаты — отправляйтесь в Доминикану.*

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что все зависит от интонации, с которой это предложение произносится.

Если подразумевается вот такая конструкция — *[**Если**] Хотите увидеть лучшие зак**а**ты, отправляйтесь в Доминикану*, — то вполне возможно поставить запятую.

Но мне кажется, что без союза *если* первая часть предложения приобретает вопросительную интонацию. Тогда пунктуация может быть такой:
*Хот**и**те увидеть лучшие закаты? Отправляйтесь в Доминикану.*

Вот похожие предложения.
Хотите увидеть настоящую пустыню Сахару? Отправляйтесь в эрг Шигага!
Хотите увидеть самые яркие закаты в горах? Отправляйтесь в Доломитовые Альпы!

Comment: В ПАС не используется интонационный анализ,  также  он не приветствуется  Обществом на нашем сайте.

Comment: @Jasmin а что такое ПАС?

Comment: @AlexB. Думаю, под ПАС подразумевался справочник: ПРАВИЛА РУССКОЙ ОРФОГРАФИИ И ПУНКТУАЦИИ. ПОЛНЫЙ АКАДЕМИЧЕСКИЙ СПРАВОЧНИК. Под ред. В.В. Лопатина
(М., 2006)
(http://www.ruslang.ru/agens.php?id=book_pravila)

Comment: @AlexB. **П**олный **А**кадемический **С**правочник, онлайн-версия: http://orthographia.ru/.

Comment: Понятно. А где там написано, что "не используется интонационный анализ"? Я сейчас посмотрю тоже.

Comment: Там нет слов " мы не используем интонационный анализ", но я не видела там объяснений, где бы ссылались на интонацию, в отличие от Розенталя.

Answer (score 0):

**Хотите увидеть лУчшие закаты – отправляйтесь в Доминикану.**

**Всё зависит от контекста,** и очень сомнительно, что он соответствует этому предложению.

**Тире можно поставить,** если речь шла о красивых закатах, а вы хотите увидеть **еще более прекрасные.**

А если это реклама вида: "Хотите увидеть лУчшие (в мире) закаты?  Тогда отправляйтесь в Доминикану", то **высказывание неправильно построено,** его нужно разделить на два отдельных предложения, первое их которых вопросительное.

**О запятой же вообще нет речи:** в БСП она ставится только для обозначения перечислительных или присоединительных отношений, а здесь ничего такого нет.

Comment: Спасибо. Правильно ли я понимаю, что если добавить в начало фразы «если» и использовать тире, то предложение будет построено корректно?

Comment: Ольга, Вы сначала уточните, какую ситуацию Вы описывате. "Речь шла о красивых закатах, а вы хотите увидеть еще более прекрасные?"